# Internet Explorer causes a hard server crash when using SSL on Node.js

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, node.js, express

I have SSL set up on Node.js (and Express.js) and it seems to be working fine on every browser other than Internet Explorer 9. Occasionally (Not always), Internet Explorer causes the server to crash with this message:

```
node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: EPIPE, Broken pipe
    at Socket._writeImpl (net.js:159:14)
    at Socket._writeOut (net.js:450:25)
    at Socket.write (net.js:377:17)
    at EncryptedStream.ondata (stream.js:36:26)
    at EncryptedStream.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at EncryptedStream._push (tls.js:299:12)
    at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:581:20)
    at CleartextStream.write (tls.js:96:13)
    at ServerResponse._writeRaw (http.js:391:28)
    at ServerResponse._send (http.js:371:15)
```

When I disable SSL I haven't come across this, so I assume it's down to this.

Initialisation code is:

```
var app = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('KeyFile.key').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('KeyFile.pem').toString()
});
...
app = app.listen(443);
```

I've tried changing various things in my code, from the view rendering, to the headers sent, to the sessions, and I've run out of ideas.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: To follow up, when deployed in our staging environment, the error changes to:

    Error: ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer

The rest is the same.

Comment: maybe fill an issue at https://github.com/joyent/node

Comment: I think I may have to. I haven't found a solution to this yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was filed as #1481 in Node's issue tracker, but seems to have disappeared.  [Searching for "1481" on github](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/search?q=1481) reveals at least part of the thread of discussion about it...

But on to the good news: I was also experiencing this problem when using v0.4.8 on OSX/Snow Leopard, but (fingers crossed) upgrading to 0.4.12 seems to have made the problem "go away".  Not the most reassuring thing, but hopefully it lets you get on with your project...